# F# ImportingConstructor on primary constructor

Tags: f#, mef

I'm using MEF and I'd like to add an `ImportingConstructorAttribute` on my primary constructor. I'm using the following trick to specify an `ImportingConstructor` which doesn't break the encapsulation or immutability of my object.

```
[<Export>]
type IntradayEngine(logger:ILogger, dummy) =

    [<ImportingConstructor>] 
    new(logger) = 
        IntradayEngine(logger, None)

    member x.Start =
        ignore

    member x.Stop = 
        ignore
```

The only other ways I see around this are:
 1. Use property injection via an `ImportAttribute` on a property (which requires making that property mutable and I'm not a fan of property injection)
 2. Make a 'default' primary constructor and add another constructor on which I add my dependency (allows my object to be in a state I don't want)

Is there anyway to do this without breaking the accessibility, mutability, or state of my object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put an attribute on the primary constructor by placing it between the type name and the arguments.

```
[<Export>]
type IntradayEngine [<ImportingConstructor>](logger:ILogger) =

    member x.Start =
        ignore

    member x.Stop = 
        ignore
```

Comment: Wow, super intuitive.